# operating systems memory management paging scheme in c

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system, paging

***I'm working on operating system `Memory Management Paging Scheme` Simulation in `C`,So Here is what i've done so far:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
  int alloc[50], base[50], frame[50], job[50];
  int i, n, pa, fs, ps, nf, temp;

clrscr();
    printf("\n\t\t PAGING\n");

    printf("\n\t Enter the physical address space:");
        scanf("%d",&pa);
    printf("\n\t Enter the page size:");
        scanf("%d",&ps);

    nf=pa/ps;
    printf("\n\t Number of frames = %d",nf);
    for(i=0;i<nf;i++)
    {
        alloc[i]=0;
        printf("Enter job number %d",i+1);
            scanf("%d",job[i]);
        if (  // If job can fit  ) {
     // Here job will fit one by one
            temp=rand()%nf;
            while( alloc[temp] == 1 )
                temp=rand()%nf;
            alloc[temp]=1;
            frame[i]=temp;
     // The main algo will come here
            base[i]=frame[i]*ps;
            printf("\n %d\t\t %d\t\t %d\t\t",i,frame[i],base[i]);

        } else {
    //If the job can not fit in the memory
            printf("Job %d Can't fit in the Memory.\n",i+1);
            break;
        }

    }
getch();
}
```

**I just want to implement the below program to what i require;**

1.*First when I enter physical address and page size according to the page number I can enter my jobs*

2.*Second Each job can fit in the number of pages according to the job size*

3.*Third Each time I enter job the `Memory Block Table (MBT)` should reload and tells how much memory available or occupied*

4.*and Finally if there is not enough space to put the larger job it gives Error*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
  int ps,np,nf,log;
  int alloc[50],base[50],frame[50],page[50];
  int i,f,n,pa,fs,pno,add,offset;
  int temp;
  int f1;
clrscr();
    printf("\n\t\t PAGING\n");
    printf("\n\t Enter the logical address space:");
        scanf("%d",&log);
    printf("\n\t Enter the page size:");
        scanf("%d",&ps);
    printf("\n\t Enter the physical address space:");
        scanf("%d",&pa);
    fs=ps;
    np=log/ps;
    nf=pa/fs;
    printf("\n\t Number of pages  = %d",np);
    printf("\n\t Number of frames = %d",nf);
    for(i=0;i<nf;i++)
        alloc[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<np;i++)
    {
        temp=rand()%nf;
        while(alloc[temp]==1)
            temp=rand()%nf;
        alloc[temp]=1;
        frame[i]=temp;
    }
    printf("\n Page No \t Frame No \t Base address ");
        for(i=0;i<np;i++)
        {
            base[i]=frame[i]*ps;
            page[i]=i;
            printf("\n%d\t\t %d\t %d\t\t",i,frame[i],base[i]);
        }
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
  int mbt[50];
  int i, j, k, pa, bs, bfree, bfree_mode, ps, js, var = 0, var2=0, jn, job;

clrscr();
    printf("\n\t\t PAGING\n");

    printf("\n\t Enter the physical address space:");
        scanf("%d",&pa);
    printf("\n\t Enter the Block size:");
        scanf("%d",&bs);
    bfree = pa / bs;
    printf("\n\t the number of blocks are = %d\n",bfree);
    bfree_mode = bfree;
    for( i = 0 ; i < bfree ; i++ ) {
        mbt[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("How many jobs do you want to enter to the memory ?\n");
        scanf("%d",&jn);
       for ( j = 0 ; j <= jn+2 ; j++  )  {

        printf("Enter %d Job size :\n",j+1);
            scanf("%d",&job);
        k = var;
        var = job / bs ;
        if (job % bs !=0)
            var +=1;
        if ( var <= bfree ) {
            var2 += var;
            for ( k ; k < var2 ; k++  ) {
                mbt[k] = j+1;
            }
            bfree -= var;
            printf("mbt[0] = OS Reserved!\n");
            for ( i = 1 ; i < bfree_mode ; i++)
                printf("mbt[%d] = %d\n",i,mbt[i]);


        }else if ( var > bfree ) {
            printf("\nThe Memory is not enough for the %d Job",j+1);
            break;
          }
    }

getch();
}
```